# Accessing a Framework file under cocoa pods

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I made a cocoapod and added a third party framework as **vendor_framework** and then I did a pod install from project to get that cocoapod, it downloads the files and frameworks however, when I try to include those headers in the bridging files, it shows "Not found" error.

I found that in **Pods-MyExample.debug.xcconfig** and 
**Pods-MyExample.release.xcconfig**, its not automatically setting up the framework search path and header search path, which it should. I added them and its working now.

Why is it not including those search paths automatically?

Comment: Any progress on this issue?

Comment: No, Its not doing automatically. Cant you do it manually?

Comment: No I am also stuck with this issue...